# Excel doesn't release memory on workbook close

Tags: excel, memory-leaks, vbscript, excel-2013, vba

I have a VBScript that opens all the excel files in a folder one by one and copies a certain range into a summary file. The summary file stays open through the entire operation, but the other files are closed after copying the range. This means that the Excel application stays open the whole time.

The problem is that Windows is holding onto each workbook even after it closes and the memory use steadily climbs. I tried to isolate the problem by disabling all add-ins and removing the personal.xlsb worksheet. I then manually opened several workbooks (no script involved) and closed them one by one. The memory use increased with each open file but did not decrease when I started closing them.

I have searched for hours now and the only answer I can find is to quit and restart the application. That's a pathetic workaround (and a pain for my script) - there has to be a better way to release closed workbook memory.

I'm running Excel 2013.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'Get summary folder location
Set StartFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the folder to summarize", 0, 5)
If StartFolder Is Nothing Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If
StartFolderName = StartFolder.self.path
Set SuperFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(StartFolderName)

'Open Excel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
NewExcelName = StartFolderName & "\Summary.xlsx"
objWorkbook.SaveAs(NewExcelName)

Call ShowSubfolders (SuperFolder)

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Save and quit
objWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit
Wscript.echo "Done"

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub ShowSubFolders(fFolder)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles

        'Open document
        Set objxls = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.path)

        'Do stuff here

        'Close Document
        objxls.Close False

    Next

    For Each Subfolder in fFolder.SubFolders
        ShowSubFolders(Subfolder)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you releasing your objects after you are closing the workbooks? Showing your code will definitely help :)

Comment: I've added the code. It seems to be an issue outside of the script, but I'm hoping there is a way to solve it with a script.

Comment: Try this `Set objxls = Nothing` after `objxls.Close False` in `Sub ShowSubFolders(fFolder)` Now try it

Comment: Already tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: `'Do stuff here` What is actually happening there?

Comment: It copies a range from an objxls sheet and pastes it into objWorkbook. There are many conditionals, but the basic commands are ".copy" on objxls, ".PasteSpecial" on objWorkbook, and ".CutCopyMode=False" on objExcel.

Comment: `I then manually opened several workbooks (no script involved) and closed them one by one. The memory use increased with each open file but did not decrease when I started closing them.` Umm I missed this part. So the script is not causing this.

Comment: Yeah... so any idea how to circumvent the default setting to leak memory?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.add-ins.com/support/out-of-memory-or-not-enough-resource-problem-with-microsoft-excel.htm) link?

Comment: I went through that list several hours ago. The most insightful statements was "Close Excel every 1-2 hours.  Excel does not seem to release all memory when workbooks are closed. Ultimately a crash will occur.  Only closing Excel will solve."

Comment: My hope is that that's not true.

Comment: Although it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try `objxls.quit`

The `Set objxls = Nothing` just destroys the object reference. The `.quit` method destroys the object itself.

Comment: `objxls` is a Workbook, so it has no .Quit method.